# no get all data when i use facebook sdk

Tags: php, facebook, symfony, facebook-graph-api

I use facebook sdk but I have error when i get data user connected

code twig and js:

```
{% extends 'base.html.twig' %}

    {% block body %}
    <a href="#" onClick="logInWithFacebook()">test</a>
    {% endblock %}

    {% block javascripts%}

    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>
      logInWithFacebook = function() {
        FB.login(function(response) {
          if (response.authResponse) {
           console.log(response);
           var $data = {
                'token': response.authResponse.accessToken,
           }
          $.ajax({
          type: "POST",
          url: "http://localhost/testfb/web/app_dev.php",
          data: $data,
          context: document.body
    }).done(function(response) {
      //console.log(response);
    });
            //alert('You are logged in &amp; cookie set!');
            // Now you can redirect the user or do an AJAX request to
            // a PHP script that grabs the signed request from the cookie.
          } else {
            alert('User cancelled login or did not fully authorize.');
          }
        });
        return false;
      };
      window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
        FB.init({
          appId: '371059814596960',
          cookie: true, // This is important, it's not enabled by default
          version: 'v2.11'
        });
      };

      (function(d, s, id){
        var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
        if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
        js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
        js.src = "https://connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js";
        fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
      }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));

    </script>


    {%endblock%}
```

code php:

```
<?php

    namespace AppBundle\Controller;

    use Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Configuration\Route;
    use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;
    use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
    use Facebook\Facebook;
    class DefaultController extends Controller
    {
        /**
         * @Route("/", name="homepage")
         */
        public function indexAction(Request $request)
        {
            // replace this example code with whatever you need

            $fb = new Facebook([
      'app_id' => '371059841209960', // Replace {app-id} with your app id
      'app_secret' => 'secret_key',
      'default_graph_version' => 'v2.11',
      ]);
        if ($request->isMethod('POST')) {
    $token = $request->request->get('token');
    $helper = $fb->getJavaScriptHelper();
    $response= $fb->get('/me?locale=en_US&fields=name,email,likes',$token);
    $userNode = $response->getGraphUser();
    var_dump($userNode);
    }
    return $this->render('default/index.html.twig', [
                'base_dir' => realpath($this->getParameter('kernel.project_dir')).DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR,
            ]);

        }
    }
```

now in response

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o8tS8.png)

in $fb->get i  add name,email and likes in fields but i response i should name and id ... how to resolve this error and i get all data for user connected (name , email,like ,picture )

Comment: I suggest you to remove the secret of your app (for security reason) from the code you posted

Comment: @mattei i update my question and i change it .. thx bro

Comment: It remains visible on edit history (secret). You must delete the question and repost it.

Comment: “_but I have error_” please [edit] your post to include the error message

Comment: @Sam Onela error is not should likes in response .. i have username and email but likes no

Answer (score 0):

You should add the right scope at the Facebook login (See the permission section in the doc [here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/permissions)). As example:

```
FB.login(function(response) {
  // handle the response
}, {scope: 'public_profile,email,user_likes'});
```

Hope this help

Comment: but now when i have gender or email or name i have try this :$response= $fb->get('/me?locale=en_US&fields=name,email,locale,gender',$token);
 but i have do all data for user connected !

Answer (score 0):

You should debug your graph api in [Graph API Explorer](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer). The advantage is, it can show you which fields you can access, and which permission you should grant to access the fields. You were trying to access the fields `email` and `likes` but you don't have such permission to access these data. The graph API Explorer will show you these messages:

> The field 'email' is only accessible on the User object after the user
>   grants the 'email' permission.
>
> The field 'likes' is only accessible on
>   the User object after the user grants the 'user_likes' permission.

After you know which permissions should be granted, you should set the scope when calling `FB.login()`, which is documented in [Facebook Javascript SDK Reference](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.login/v2.11#permissions).

```
FB.login(function(response) {
  // handle the response
}, {scope: 'email,user_likes'});
```

However, not all users' data are available to access. According to [Permissions Reference](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/permissions):

> Basic permissions, (public_profile, user_friends, and email) do not
>   require Review, but all other permissions do.

Comment: i add them but also errors .. i add user_likes in js and i add @fields=name,likes but also error ...

Comment: you should check permissions reference, most permissions require review, https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/permissions/#reference-user_likes

Comment: i should this but i didn't how to add in code php !!